# Libre Office Maximum numbers of cell

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-basic

I have a **column** with phone numbers in Libre Office document.
How can i set maximum numbers of ***cell*** to take only 10 numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the cells of interest then use **Data > Validity** to open the validity dialog.

On the Criteria tab, set the Allow drop down to "Text Length". 
Set Data to less than or equal

Set maximum to 10.